# Cannot fit a modal window with google chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I want to show modal window with google chart inside after pressing a button.

But my is always looks very ugly and don't fit the modal size.

What I want to do that increase size of modal, increase the size of the chart and put them together for good-looking.

Here the result I have, it looks like: 
[image: chart in modal]

Here the html for modal:

```
<button id="getChart" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"> Result</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="chart" id="chart_div"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div id='png'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the CSS styles:

```
    .chart {
    align-content: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .modal:before {
        content: " ";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-footer {
    color: #00b5e6;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And js code:

```
$('#getChart').click(getCheckboxesValues);

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartObject);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        curveType: 'none',
        legend: {position: 'bottom'}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    // The select handler. Call the chart's getSelection() method
    function selectHandler() {
        var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
        if (selectedItem) {
            var task = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            alert('The user selected ' + task);
        }
    }

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Please include runnable code.

Comment: @sumesh-tg I can't include executable code of page because i take some data from the server. But i've create an pretty equivalent page on codepen, and mock data for chart to pretty close format that i receive from server. Here the link https://codepen.io/Armen91/pen/vVbOmW

Comment: I think the problem is in data in X axis. because if chart not in modal window it displays at an angle and don't covers each other. But in modal it displays straight in line. But anyway i want properly increase both sizes - for modal and and for chart also.

Comment: too many data in x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the actual `date` (not a string) as a key for data and `format: 'YYYY-MM-dd'` to properly format date for a chart.

check this:

```
google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['date', 'speedKpi'],
  [new Date('2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z'), 66.60145829628313],
  [new Date('2018-10-02T00:00:00.000Z'), 329.1959406713505],
  [new Date('2018-10-03T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-05T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-06T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-07T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-08T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-09T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-10T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-11T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-12T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-13T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-14T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-15T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-16T00:00:00.000Z'), 72.62773722627736],
  [new Date('2018-10-17T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-18T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-19T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-20T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-21T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-22T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-23T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-24T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-25T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0],
  [new Date('2018-10-26T00:00:00.000Z'), 0.0]
]);
```

...

```
var options = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  curveType: 'none',
  legend: { position: 'bottom' }, hAxis: { format: 'YYYY-MM-dd' }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Also, you can use `slantedText` option to rotate keys a bit, so you'll be able to see them:

```
hAxis: {slantedText: true}
```

Summary here: https://codepen.io/extempl/pen/aRXvLY

Please also check [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) for more options and control over the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks much better! Occasionally maybe you know how can I increase the size of modal and chart, because when I use size attributes they don’t fit each other and misplaying.

Comment: `options: {width: 1000}` will increase chart's width. But there is also style for modal which should be overwritten with `.modal-dialog {
    max-width: none;
}`